# In a finite dimensional inner product space with $T ∈ L(V)$, show that $\langle u,v\rangle = \langle T(u),T(v)\rangle$ implies $T$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Here is how I've tried to go about it, and I'm curious if it's true or if I'm way off base.

T is invertible iff null$(T)=\{0\}$. Let $v∈V$ and suppose $T(v)=0$. If we can show that $v=0$, then $T$ is invertible.

Consider $\langle v,v\rangle = \langle T(v),T(v)\rangle = \langle 0,0 \rangle = 0$, and $\langle v,v\rangle = 0$ iff $v=0$.

Does this prove the statement? Or are there any other thoughts or methods?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks good to me!

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate your comment.

Comment: That's the way to go. Nice proof.

Comment: Exercise: explicitly construct (find?) the inverse. Hint: use that $x^Ty = \langle x,y \rangle$ for a clearer picture.

Comment: @Nitin What does the notation x^T mean?

Comment: Transpose. It's fairly common notation

Comment: Oh yes, I've seen that notation. I got confused for a moment and thought you meant the transformation T from the problem and didn't know if there was certain notation about that I was unaware of. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: In order to construct the inverse in a general inner product space, I decided to use the definition of the adjoint of T, T*. Since ⟨v,u⟩ = ⟨T(v), T(u)⟩ = ⟨v,T*(T(u))⟩, this implies that u = T*(T(u)), and therefore the adjoint of T, T*, is our inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Given: $u^Tv$ = $(Tu)^T(Tv)$

To Prove: T is invertible.

Proof: $u^Tv$ = $(Tu)^T(Tv)$ = $u^TT^T(Tv)$ = $u^T(T^TT)v$

i.e. $u^Tv$ = $u^T(T^TT)v$ , therefore $T^TT$ = $I$ (Identity matrix)

$T^TT$ = $I$ implies that combinations of rows of $T$ can generate the basis of row space of $I$ matrix. Therefore $T$ is invertible.